# VLOOKUP - Linking Documents

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, vlookup

I am using Libreoffice calc and trying to link values on 2 separate documents

Doc 1 take the form

```
  id    parent ID    Title       Att1    Att2    Price    Reg Price    Stock
 1001      0         Prod1                       
 1002     1001       Prod1-A      A       A     £10.99      £10.99      10
 1003      0         Prod2        
 1004     1003       Prod2-A      A       A     £11.99      £11.99      20
 1005     1003       Prod1-B      B       B     £11.99      £11.99      15
```

This is the document I will be updating.

Doc 2 is the file I want to auto populate from these results and takes the form

```
  ID    Parent ID    Title    Price    Sale Price    Stock
 1001      0         Prod1                       
 1002     1001       Prod1-A   
 1003      0         Prod2        
 1004     1003       Prod2-A   
 1005     1003       Prod1-B
```

I want to populate Doc 2 from Doc 1 and have tried using VLOOKUP.

I have used the formula (example from first empty price box in doc 2):

```
=VLOOKUP(A3,'file:///C:/Users/computer/Desktop/folder/Product details.xlsx'#$'Sheet1'.$A$3:$F$99,3,0)
```

This does not seem to return any results.

Could someone advise where i might be going wrong?

Comment: While you're entering the formula, instead of typing the path for the lookup table, navigate to the document (Doc 1) and select the range manually.  Excel will enter the correct path.  It may not show the full C:/users... etc. path, but it will show if you close Doc 1.  Also, you have specified column 3 as the result column.  It looks like it should be 6 from the sample data you've shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Bandersnatch pretty much hit the nail on the head.  Here is a screen capture showing how to select the range.  The result is £10.99.

[image: select range manually]

Comment: Thank you for the example. daft mistake on my part. This is my first time using VLOOKUP and I wasnt 100% sure what the different cells where looking for. understand much better now.

Answer (score -1):

The following points need to be re-checked:

1. The file path which is seen in your formula appears to be in a reverse order.
   Normally, when we type a path, we use a back-slash '\' whereas, here a '/' is
   used. Have you entered the path manually ?
2. Check if the Calculation Mode in your Excel is by-any-chance
   set to 'manual' instead of 'automatic'
3. Check if the ID in both the DOC are same type.
   I mean - if one is numeric and the other is character then that also could be
   a reason for not getting the desired answer.

Hope this Helps.

Comment: It's actually a URL, so it uses `/` as a separator.  See https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Referencing_a_Cell_in_Another_Document.